# Parsing HTML file using Xpath in JAVA

Tags: java, xpath, web-scraping, html-content-extraction, htmlcleaner

I have a Java code that could read the source of a URL and save to a file(source.html) and now from the saved page, I want to extract some value using XPath. Suppose I want to read the price - `//div [@itemprop='price'] //text ()`

How to do this further, Will I be able to do this directly in the saved HTML page or I should first convert this to an XML file and then use XPath. I have heard about HTML cleaners/Parsers should I use this here ?  Please do not point to another website for answers. If so route me to a spot where I can make a direct and simple lesson. Modifying the below code would be highly helpful.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class jSoupContentRead {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileWriter FR = new FileWriter("source.html");
        PrintWriter op = new PrintWriter(FR);

        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(
                "http://itunes.apple.com/us/book/a-way-home/id982665320?mt=11")
                .get();

        op.write(doc.toString());
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using JSoup. Its query language allows something very similar, why go with XPath?

Comment: @ RealSkeptic - you are correct but i prefer xpath as it is very easy for me to use.

Comment: If you truly "like to learn", then learn JSoup as @RealSkeptic suggests as it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: Xpath is handy and has some advanced functions which jsoup doesnt. Also i could get a lot of help for xpath in net where jsoup has limited docs. So could someone pls help me with an example.

Comment: `"Xpath ... has some advanced functions which jsoup doesnt..."` -- such as?

Comment: I want to cover functions like translate, substring, div, round off , normalize-space. Jsoup might have all these but i am not able to get help easily from net. And my use case here is to use xpath and not jsoup. So please help me with it.

Comment: So is there anyone to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally (cross languages) XPath is to be applyied to the DOM structure. In php there is a standart procedure:

1. Get html
2. Make it a valid xml (might be an optional step)
3. Make of it a DOMDocument object instance
4. Make of it a DOMXPath object instance
5. Apply xpath query to this DOMXPath instance. See an [example in php](https://webscraping.pro/using-domxpath-for-parsing-page-content-in-php/).

I think there should be something similar in JAVA.